# BeautifulSoup 4 returns only a part of the input tag

Tags: javascript, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the values from 'name' tag of an input tag.

Eg: `<input type='text' id='my_id' name='input_tag_name' autocomplete="off">`

But when I do:

```
my_soup.find("input", attrs={'id': 'my_id'})
```

, the bs4 is giving me exactly the following output:

```
<input id='my_id' type='text'/>
```

As you can observe it is missing the other fields.

I have tried the followings:

1. `my_soup = bs4(my_html, 'html5lib')`
2. `my_soup = bs4(my_html, 'html')`

How can I get the name value from this input tag?

**Note**: The my_html is a response from a server and it is a normal sized HTML file which is confidential and I cannot share it.

Comment: Probably the _javascript_ is adding the _tag attributes_. Check the script tags javascript code

Comment: In fact you are right I should have checked the Source Code itself that I was getting in response. Looks like the field is not populated when I get the response. So it has to be JavaScript HTML DOM.